# What are some comprehensive, reliable resources to learn about the Malankara Orthodox Syrian Church?

Tags: church-history, conversion, oriental-orthodox, christianity-in-india

Dear community members,

I am eager to learn more about the Malankara Orthodox Syrian Church as well as about the Oriental Orthodox Communion in general. Please provide resources for someone with no prior knowledge of Christianity.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Have you read the wikipedia articles? They provide a nice overview as well as links to resources.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE, and thanks for taking the site tour. For more on what this site is all about, see: [How we are different than other sites](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1808/20394).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Oriental Orthodox Church is comprised of six sister churches all of which are in communion with one another. These six churches include

1. Armenian Orthodox Church
2. Coptic Orthodox Church
3. Ethiopian Orthodox Tewahedo Church
4. Eritrean Orthodox Tewahedo Church
5. Syrian Orthodox Church
6. Malankara Orthodox Syrian Church

The Malankara Orthodox Syrian Church was founded by St. Thomas the Apostle who preached to India in the year 52 AD. It is headed by H.H. Baselios
Marthoma Paulose II. His Grace Bishop Youssef, Bishop of the Coptic Orthodox Southern Diocese of the United States, recently went on a Mission Trip and met with the Pope and other clergies, which shows the love between the two churches

Each of these Oriental Churches is Orthodox and accept the Councils of Nicea, Constantinople, and Ephesus. They each have the same faith. This is different than the Mar Thoma church. The Malankara church is known as an Orthodox Church while Mar Thoma is not in communion with the other Orthodox Churches listed above.

Each Oriental Orthodox Church holds the same faith in these areas, just to name a few, and therefore are in communion with each other.

1. The Orthodox Creed
2. The Divinity of Christ
3. The Holy Sacraments
4. Soteriology
5. Christology

More information about the Malankara Orthodox Syrian Church can be found directly from [Malankara Orthodox Syrian Church Website](http://mosc.in/the_church/what-do-we-believe).

[Video of H.G. Bishop Youssef Mission Experience in 2016 with HE Metropolitan Gabriel Mar Gregorios](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=josXhZeCBxQ)